# Handling js.erb files in Rails 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am converting a standard scaffold generated application to use AJAX and JQuery in a similar manner to that specified in http://stjhimy.com/posts/07-creating-a-100-ajax-crud-using-rails-3-and-unobtrusive-javascript.

I followed all the instructions :

- Creating a composite Index view using 2 partials;
- Updated the Controller,only retaining Index, Create, Edit,Update and Destroy actions;
- created js.erb files for the Create, edit, update and destroy actions that use JQuery functions to update the DOM.

Can't seem to access the js.erb files at all. Put the js.erb in the with the view files , for example `app/views/customers/create.js.erb`

The code for the create.js.erb is :

```
<% if @customer.errors.any? -%> 

   /*Hide the Flash Notice div*/
   $("#flash_notice").hide(300);

   /*Update the html of the div customer_errors with the new one*/
   $("#customer_errors").html("<% @customer.errors.full_message.each do |msg| %>
                              <li><%= msg %></li>
                              <% end %>");

   /*Show the div customer_errors*/
   $("#cust0mer_errors").show(300);

<% else -%>

   /*Hide the div customer_errors*/
   $("#customer_errors").hide(300);

   /*Update the html of the div flash_notice with the new one */
   $("#flash_notice").html("<%= flash[:notice] %>");

   /*Show the flash_notice div*/
   $("#flash_notice").show(300);

   /*Clear the entire form*/
   $(":input:not(input[type=submit])").val("");

   /*Replace the html of the div posts_list with the updated new one*/
   $("#customers_list").html("<%= render "customers" %>";

   <% end %>
```

The code for the forms is below:

The index.html.erb file

```
<div id="customer_form"><%= render 'form' %></div>
<div id="customers_list"><%= render 'customers' %></div>
```

The _form.html,erb partial file

```
<%= form_for(@customer, :remote => true) do |f| %>


  <div id="customer_errors" style="display:none"></div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :firstname %>
    <%= f.text_field :firstname %>
    <%= f.label :lastname %>
    <%= f.text_field :lastname %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
    <%= f.label :phone %>
    <%= f.text_field :phone %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.text_field :password %>
    <%= f.label :address_id %>
    <%= f.text_field :address_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The file for the _customers.html.erb partial is:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Password</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @customers.each do |customer| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= customer.firstname %></td>
    <td><%= customer.lastname %></td>
    <td><%= customer.email %></td>
    <td><%= customer.phone %></td>
    <td><%= customer.password %></td>
    <td><%= customer.address_id %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_customer_path(customer), :remote => true %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', customer, :remote => true, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

---

**Edit**

latest version of Customers controller:

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :load

  def load
    @customers = Customer.all
    @customer  = Customer.new
  end

  def index   
  end


  def create
    @customer = Customer.new(params[:customer])
    if @customer.save
      flash[:notice] = "Customer was successfully created."
      @customers = Customer.all
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end 

    end
  end 

  def edit
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  def update
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    if @customer.update_attributes(params[:customer])
      flash[:notice] = "Customer was successfully updated."
      @customers = Customer.all
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end   
    end
  end  

  def destroy
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    @customer.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Customer successfully destroyed"
    @customers = Customer.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

The latest version of layout template has include tags as follows after I chanse the Jquery.js fille to rails.js

```
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js' %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag 'rails' %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

Latest logs:

```
Started GET "/customers" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Dec 14 21:16:14 +0000 2011
  Processing by CustomersController#index as HTML
  Customer Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "customers".* FROM "customers"
Rendered customers/_form.html.erb (14.1ms)
Rendered customers/_customers.html.erb (28.1ms)
Rendered customers/index.html.erb within layouts/application (47.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 74ms (Views: 56.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)


Started GET "/customers/13/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Dec 14 21:17:20 +0000 2011
  Processing by CustomersController#edit as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"13"}
  Customer Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "customers".* FROM "customers"
  Customer Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "customers".* FROM "customers" WHERE "customers"."id" = 13 LIMIT 1
Rendered customers/_form.html.erb (16.1ms)
Rendered customers/edit.js.erb (17.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 43ms (Views: 27.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)


Started GET "/customers/13/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Dec 14 21:17:31 +0000 2011
  Processing by CustomersController#edit as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"13"}
  Customer Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "customers".* FROM "customers"
  Customer Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "customers".* FROM "customers" WHERE "customers"."id" = 13 LIMIT 1
Rendered customers/_form.html.erb (25.9ms)
Rendered customers/edit.js.erb (28.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 52ms (Views: 39.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)


Started DELETE "/customers/18" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Dec 14 21:18:31 +0000 2011
  Processing by CustomersController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"18"}
  Customer Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "customers".* FROM "customers"
  Customer Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "customers".* FROM "customers" WHERE "customers"."id" = 18 LIMIT 1
  AREL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "customers" WHERE "customers"."id" = 18
  Customer Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "customers".* FROM "customers"
Rendered customers/_customers.html.erb (120.3ms)
Rendered customers/destroy.js.erb (122.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 198ms (Views: 134.1ms | ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)


Started GET "/customers" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Dec 14 21:20:00 +0000 2011
  Processing by CustomersController#index as HTML
  Customer Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "customers".* FROM "customers"
Rendered customers/_form.html.erb (19.1ms)
Rendered customers/_customers.html.erb (23.8ms)
Rendered customers/index.html.erb within layouts/application (50.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 76ms (Views: 54.9ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6m
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create your `form` and `link_to` objects, you need to make sure they have a `:remote => true` on them otherwise the route will not render the action via JS.  Instead, it will render it with the default HTML.

An example:

```
<%= form_for(@post, :remote => true) do |f| %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(post), :remote => true %>
```

Also, make sure you have the latest jQuery and jQuery Rails adapter installed: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs

As a side note, you don't need `format.html` in your code above if you're doing 100% ajax for the CRUD actions since all you'll ever render are the JS files (format.js).

---

**Update:**
I think you are misunderstanding a few things... The tutorial you are reading only talks about changing the CRUD (create, read, update, delete) actions into 100% ajax calls which means they are the only ones that will respond with rendering `.js.erb` files.  So when you are checking that the page is `Processing SomeController#some_action as JS` it will **only** apply to the `create`, `show`, `update`, and `destroy` actions within your Customers controller.

**For the jQuery and jQuery-UJS install on Rails 3.0**, follow these directions:

> Be sure to get rid of the rails.js file if it exists, and instead use the new jquery_ujs.js file that gets copied to the public directory. Choose to overwrite jquery_ujs.js if prompted.

Then run `rails generate jquery:install`

Change your layout template to this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

I have to say, that tutorial you are reading is about the worst tutorial I've ever read.  Since you seem to be very new to Ruby on Rails so I would *highly* recommend reading a different tutorial (like this one if you still want to read about AJAX w/ Rails: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/ or even something really good like this one to learn Rails itself better: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book).

Comment: I have put the forms up - anything else you want ?

Comment: Can you post the server logs from when you submit a form post or click a link?  Also, check the browser's console to see if any JS errors are there.

Comment: Put what I could up there - also fixed few typos with the create.js.erb file. Great to know one is not alone.

Comment: You still have an error in your `create` controller action: `@customers = customer.all` should be `@customers = Customer.all`... and also, another error in your `create.js.erb` file:  `$("#cust0mer_errors").show(300);` should be `$("#customer_errors").show(300);` Can you also verify that you installed jQuery and the jQuery Rails adapter (https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) and removed the `format.html` references?

Comment: The reason I keep asking about jQuery is because your Rails server logs show `Processing by CustomersController#create as HTML` (format.html) but if the JS call was working correctly (via jQuery), then it should have been `Processing by CustomersController#create as JS` (format.js) instead

Comment: I have made the changes and installed jquery from the github site. I modified the Gemfile and ran bundle install and then put in rails generate jquery --ui. This seemed to work fine, but then O had an error - "routing error missing rails.js fire". I renamed jquery.js to rails.js  and that error disappeared. I am still having trouble - the edit action still seems to cause an HTML processing request and the destroy action seems to look for a show action. I have included the logs below along with the latest code from the controller.

Comment: I am getting a 406 error, which appears to be a mismatch between the reply format in the initial equest and what is sent back

Comment: I havre put in details of logs, controllers, include tag details etc in the post above.

Comment: Joe, Please see my updated answer.  Also, the reason you are getting the `show` error is because you don't have a `def show` action in your **CustomersController**.  I hate to say it, but that tutorial you are reading is terrible and it seems to be doing nothing but causing you more confusion.  I linked to a couple good tutorials in my updated answer.

Comment: I get this " show action not found"  when I am trying to execute the destroy action - any ideas about the 406 errors - sorry to keep bothering you.

Comment: Joe, like I said, ditch that tutorial and read one of the ones that I linked to.  I'm sorry, but I can't keep trying to help you when the tutorial you are reading is useless.

Comment: The tutorial is not a great example of clarity - I looked up the article by Gadbois and ploughed my wat through Michael Hartl's tutorial. Unfortunately, I am having to learn Ror, JavaScript, C# etc and deliver a number of assignments from scratch in 3-4 months. Although I have been many years in IT, I have not been at the coalface for a long time. This is a real burden for a 62 year old man. Bear with me - I really appreciate your assistance.

Comment: I am now getting through the controller - but the server is rendering a partial as well as the js.erb file. I will append the log to this submission.

Comment: 406 error now gone - reloaded the system after reinstalling Jquery - nearly there logs now up.

Comment: Nearly there after reinstalling Jquery and re-initialising the Ubuntu VM. Still something wrong with the Javascript / JQuery calls in the js.erb files. Getting there and thanks very much for your interest and patience.

Comment: The key was the JQuery libraries - everything fell into place after that. I have a JavaScript problem that I just posted, if your feeling bored. Thanks to iWasRobbed.

Comment: Glad to help, Joe.  If you can do me a favor and hit the checkmark next to my answer, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Found it  - on the left hand side.

Comment: I have two remaining problems that I am finding hard to resolve: a) Don't know how to reset the submit type on the partial yo new after an update and get stuck constantly updating, b) Error message are not displaying, even though the code is taking that path in the relevant js.erb file create and update. Any ideas IWasRobbed ?

Comment: I have replaced the full_message term in the code above with full_messages. Still get the same problem.  iWasRobbed.

Comment: Joe, please ask those things as a new question on StackOverflow.  This way, everything stays more organized and is easier to debug using your current code (rather than the old code above)

Comment: Will do that now. I will put up the Controller, Partials and the js.erb files. As you can probably see I am being driven demented by the getJSON problem.

Comment: I posted an answer on that `getJSON` problem so go check it out when you get the chance.  I got it working fine in my local rails server